# shortcut to delete the current page in LibreOffice writer

Tags: shortcut-keys, libreoffice

Is there a known shortcut in LibreOffice writer for deleting the current page of the document without affecting other pages?

By deleting I mean the entire page, not just the content.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but requires multiple key combinations to achieve. There is no single "kill page" keyboard shortcut option.

I'd recommend setting up a new document with (say) 3 pages with some text at the beginning of each (like page1, page2, page3) just to understand the operation and to experiment. A new page can be easily invoked using <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> after each. Always ensure you have a copy of your work before undertaking these types of operation to be on the safe side although you can always use the "undo" option if it goes wrong.

HINT: The use <kbd>Ctrl+F10</kbd> to toggle the formatting marks. You will see the where the paragraph formatting marks have been placed whilst experimenting
[image]

So, to directly answer your question, place the cursor before the first character in the page you wish to delete to ensure all the text is selected then press <kbd>Shift+PageDown</kbd> to highlight all the text on the page. Ensure the cursor lands on the next page (you want to retain) just ahead of the first character on that page. This will ensure that the page break marker is included.

Then go back to the top of the page you wish to delete - scroll up to do this as any other key press will remove the text selection.

As the text on the page is already selected <kbd>Shit+Delete</kbd> then deletes the text and thus the page (provided the page break marker is included).

Answer (score 0):

A page in a word processor is a temporary artifact. Delete a paragraph, and the content of the page has changed. Perhaps for this reason, no default keybindings to select the contents of a page are defined by default. Still, it can be made easy to select a page in two steps with two shortcut keys.

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> brings you to the top of the current page
2. If you define your own shortcut key for the function "Select to begin of page", that shortcut will select up to the next page.

You can define your own shortcut keys in "Tools" — "Customize", "Keyboard" tab. This could be further automated to a single shortcut key using the Macro facility of Libreoffice.

Other ways to quickly select larger chunks of text include

- Place the cursor on top of the page, and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking the last character on the page to select the current page content
- Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp/Dn</kbd> to quickly select larger portions of text.
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> to quickly select subsequent paragraphs at once